# Unable to connect to MongoDB server from host to VM

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, virtual-machine

I'am trying to connect to a MongoDB server using mongoose but without much success, also the reason why my MongoDB server is in a VM is because MongoDB does not support Ubuntu 22.04 which I'm currently using.

Here's my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true)

const uri = 'mongodb://192.168.137.66:27017/test';
const options = {
    autoIndex: false,
    maxPoolSize: 10,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
    family: 4
};

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect(uri, options);
}
```

There is a communication established between the host and the VM and the MongoDB is running as showcased in the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1snVZ.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 How does the `mongod.conf` file look like? Maybe set `bindIpAll: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `bindIpAll: true` in the `mongod.conf` file fixed my problem.